# Rails - before_action login for create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

**Leaving this question open for now, but with a better understanding of the problem, I have reposted it - [Devies - route to action with 'POST' request after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019458/devies-route-to-action-with-post-request-after-login)**

My Rails app uses Devise for user authentication, and I am trying to set it up so that the `create` action for my controller requires a successful login.  I've almost got this working, but I am running into a small problem - a form is filled out on the `new` page, then the user is asked to log in, but then rather than proceeding to the `create` action (and subsequent redirect to a summary page), the user is logged in and then redirected *back* to the `new` page.  Here's the code...

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:create]

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
        @post.save
        redirect_to posts_summary_path
    end
end
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || posts_path
end
```

So ideally, the chain of events would be `new` -> `login` -> `create` -> `summary`, but instead what I'm getting is `new` -> `login` -> `new` -> `create` -> `summary`.  Why is the session_controller.rb redirecting to the `new` action instead of `create`?  Raking my routes suggests that I've got the redirect destination correct...

```
posts POST   /posts(.:format)              posts#create
```

I had tried removing the sessions_controller.rb from the routes and just rely on the default Devise behavior but this automatically redirects to a login success page and doesn't trigger the `create` action.

Comment: What is after_sign_in_path_for returning in your sessions_controller? If you're not using omniauth, then it's probably evaluating stored_location_for(resource).  What's that value?

Comment: Hmmm... well, I'm not proud to say it, but I don't know.  Where might I find that?

Comment: If I change `posts_path` in the sessions_controller.rb above to one of the other paths, it works fine.  Just not for the create action...

Comment: @hightempo I got a little bit farther - I was trying to use a custom pathname on my `new` action that made the url just `/posts/`, and I think that this was somewhat confusing for Devise.  I changed the route back to `/posts/new` and kept the Devise controller the same, but now I get an error that `no route matches 'get' posts` which is true... the posts_path is a 'post', not a 'get' - can I specify the verb in the redirect from the Devise controller?

Comment: @hightempo - yes, I think that the verb is the problem.  I created an `index` route which would match the `'get' posts` route, and sure enough, it redirected to the new index view.  So the question remains... how to redirect to a route with a 'post' verb?  Now that I understand the problem better, I am going to repost my question.

Comment: @hightempo - With a better understanding of what's happening, I have re-asked this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019458/devies-route-to-action-with-post-request-after-login

Comment: OK.  It sounds to me like you're not using a debugging tool at all.  I'd recommend using one.  For future reference, you can always do simple debugging in your application using puts.  The results will show in your application logs.  So in this case you could do something like `puts stored_location_for(resource)`.  That will get you basic information like the value of a variable. I would also recommend taking the next step and using a Rails debugging gem like rails_pry or byebug.