# Devies - route to action with 'POST' request after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my Rails app, I am using Devise for user authentication.  I am trying to set it so that the `create` action of a controller has a `before_action :authenticate_user!` filter, but I am running into a problem - the default behavior of the Devise `after_sign_in_path_for` controller action seems only to be able to redirect to a route with a 'get' verb, but the `create` action relies on 'post'.  How can I set it so that the redirect points to the correct action?

routes.rb

```
resources :posts, only: [:index, :new, :create]
```

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:create]

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
        @post.save
        redirect_to posts_summary_path
    end  
end
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || posts_path
end
```

and from my rake routes

```
posts GET    /posts(.:format)    posts#index
      POST   /posts(.:format)    posts#create
```

So as it stands, the user is asked to log in after form submission on the `new` page, but instead of redirecting to and completing the `create` action after log in, Devise routes the user to the `index` view.  If I remove the `index` route, I get the error `No route matches [GET] "/reports"` which is true, but I am trying to route to `[POST] "reports"`, not `[GET]`.

Is there a way that I can specify that this is supposed to be a post, not a get?

Comment: Redirection isn't possible using `post` requests. You can either force the user to sign in before hitting the `new` page or you could store the entered information in the session variables and submit it after redirect. For the latter see this article: https://blog.justinthiele.com/retaining-form-data-through-a-login-process-a/

Comment: I see - thank you for the article, I think that will do what I need.